# Arc chrome with obb files

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I'm searching to play a game that has an OBB file for its data. I have the file and the apk, but ARC welder doesn't seem to have a way to select the OBB file directory. Is there another way to allow the app access to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, you just have to launch the app once, let it crash, and then place the obb file in the "Android/obb" subfolder of the unpacked extension.
See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeapks/comments/31zqfb/got_monument_valley_running_in_arc_welder_fully/) for more info.